# Unable to establish Xdebug connection without IDEKEY

Tags: php, xdebug

I am trying to get xdebug working and I can't tell at this point if I'm missing some fundamental component to xdebug or it's xdebug itself. I've visited numerous tutorials and guides, and have had no luck.

So I setup my xdebug config as follows:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
#xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.56.1
#xdebug.remote_port = 9000
#xdebug.idekey = xdebug-atom

xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 8
```

I'm trying on PhpStorm and VSCode. In PhpStorm, when I use their "Zero-configuration debugging", it starts listening, but hitting a page directly or using POSTMAN has no affect. I do occasionally get the following error in the log:

```
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.56.1:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
```

When I set a server in PhpStorm, it seems to activate and hold a connection, but again, no breaks on breakpoints. In VSCode, it also seems to activate and listen, but nothing, and I haven't seen anything in the log from my VSCode attempts.

When I set the `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie in POSTMAN, I do notice it breaks, but from so many tutorials, it seem to indicate this isn't necessary with remote_connect_back? As you can see, I have the idekey commented out. Am I wrong and you do need the cookie, regardless?

How can I figure out what's wrong? I've been through the xdebug docs, the PhpStorm docs relating to Xdebug, and I don't know how many blog posts.

Comment: I have bad news, even though they list it as compatible with xdebug, it won't work. I can't find my support ticket from last year, but they recognized it won't work.
 I switched to eclipse, and it works like a charm

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni You mean PHPStorm? I know it can work because most of my office uses PHPStorm and many of them use XDebug just fine.

Comment: Yup, I meant PHPStorm, perhaps they fixed it, but on November 2016, they told me it was not possible.

Comment: Xdebug works fine in PHPStorm and it did in November 2016 as well

Comment: @RhoVisions: Does is stop if you activate this in PHPStorm?

Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug->Beak at first line in PHP scripts

Comment: @Fels It didn't at first, but I realized part of my problem was my firewall. Unblocking port 9000 helped, but only if I set an explicit idekey. According to so many tutorials, I shouldn't need to set one with remote connect back, so not sure again if I don't understand something, or its working as intended. Also not sure if I should close this question and open another relating to that problem specifically, or update this one.

Comment: @Fels Nevermind, I realized that it's only working in POSTMAN when I have the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie set. So connect back isn't working, just the session listening. Which is better than nothing I guess...

Comment: 1) With `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` you do not need to have any XDEBUG_COOKIE or similar GET parameter .. as with that option xdebug will attempt to debug every single request. 2) I'd say it's better to have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0` and specify correct IP in `xdebug.remote_host` 3) The rest -- well.. may depend on your config etc -- not enough info. 4) Also ... if you are debugging a web page/service .. then make sure that you are checking current xdebug settings via `phpinfo()` output captured via browser .. as on some OS you may have different php.ini for CLI and web server.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.56.1:9000.
> E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
> ```

That often indicates that there is either nothing listening on port 9000, or that there is a firewall in the way that prevents Xdebug from making a connection to the IDE.

> When I set the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie in POSTMAN, I do notice it
>   breaks, but from so many tutorials, it seem to indicate this isn't
>   necessary with remote_connect_back? As you can see, I have the idekey
>   commented out. Am I wrong and you do need the cookie, regardless?

The "idekey" is irrelevant if you're just on your own debugging your own application. It only comes into play with DBGp proxies (which is outside the scope of this question). Only on the CLI, Xdebug cares about that the idekey is **set** through `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=yourname"`. But as you're not doing CLI debugging here, its value does not matter.

`xdebug.remote_connect_back` only deals with selecting which IP to connect to, it does not make a difference to whether Xdebug will try to connect.

To connect, there needs to be the `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie (or `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` GET parameter), **or**, you can set [xdebug.remote_autostart](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_autostart), in which case Xdebug will attempt to make a connection to the IDE on every request regardless of the cookie.

Please be also aware that the title of this question is misleading. The IDE will **not** make a connection to Xdebug, it is Xdebug that makes a connection to the IDE.